# System.DirectoryServices AuthenticationTypes

Tags: .net, security, authentication, active-directory

Normally I have been using `Secure | Signing | Sealing` flags to pull back a directory entry and search.

If I wanted to use SecureSocketsLayer instead, should I also specify any of those flags (`Secure | Signing | Sealing`) with it, or does the SSL flag encompass full encryption/signing and can be used alone?

I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx but the description doesn't make it fully clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SecureSocketsLayer requires a user cert - it's mutual auth, essentially. It's not the same as Secure | Signing | Sealing. This gets you Kerberos/NTLM authenticated and encrypted traffic. If you don't need mutual auth, I would leave it as-is, but, if you do, you can attach it as a fourth flag.

Comment: so SSL only gets me mutual authentication and no encryption? I need all 4 flags for that?

Comment: @BrianDesmond ,Your statement "but, if you do, you can attach it as a fourth flag", If you mean like adding 'AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer' flag will have SSL mode of communication, then its wrong; Just test it simply with this code; "var flags = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing | AuthenticationTypes.Encryption | AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;" If you check 'flags' property only 3 will be set;